# Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-evolutions

I am using Play framework 2.7.3, and evolution is always creating wrong sql no matter what I do

I tried to edit generated sql, but after loading the project evolution is becoming the way it was before

## this is in my application.conf

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playstudent?serverTimezone=EST5EDT"
db.default.username=root
ebean.default = ["models.*"]

#my build.sbt look like this
#=============================


name := """MyFirstPlay"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)
libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += jdbc
libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
libraryDependencies += javaWs

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.16"

libraryDependencies += "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "javax.activation" % "activation" % "1.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.jaxb" % "jaxb-runtime" % "2.3.2"



playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("models.*")
playEbeanDebugLevel := 4
```

## I expect generated sql to be correct but am getting this error

play.api.db.evolutions.InconsistentDatabase: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state![An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and
 resolve it manually before marking it as resolved.]
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.$anonfun$checkEvolutionsState$3(EvolutionsApi.scala:309)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.$anonfun$checkEvolutionsState$3$adapted(EvolutionsApi.scala:294)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.executeQuery(EvolutionsApi.scala:341)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.checkEvolutionsState(EvolutionsApi.scala:294)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.databaseEvolutions(EvolutionsApi.scala:145)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:120)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:135)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:99)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$.$anonfun$runEvolutions$1(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:206)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:232)
[error] application -

! @7ch9a8n6b - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.db.evolutions.InconsistentDatabase: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state![An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and
 resolve it manually before marking it as resolved.]
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.$anonfun$checkEvolutionsState$3(EvolutionsApi.scala:309)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.$anonfun$checkEvolutionsState$3$adapted(EvolutionsApi.scala:294)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.executeQuery(EvolutionsApi.scala:341)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.checkEvolutionsState(EvolutionsApi.scala:294)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.databaseEvolutions(EvolutionsApi.scala:145)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:120)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:135)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:99)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$.$anonfun$runEvolutions$1(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:206)
        at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:232)

Comment: what kind of corrections you making to generated sql ?

Comment: I think it was the problem of mysql version I changed to mysql 8.0.17 and it worked successful